# Writing very small characters on top of image OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

So Im trying to write a single character using putText() on top of an image to fit into a 25x25 box but the text is too small to render, it just looks like a blob of whatever color I choose the text to be. Is there any way to create small, readable text to overlay onto an image with OpenCV?

Comment: If there are just a few possible characters, pre-create them as small Mats and copy the corresponding one over the big image.

Comment: Make a 25x25 image in Photoshop or GIMP for each possible character and load the corresponding image when you want to draw it... and add **Font Designer** to your CV;-)

Comment: Did you try the fontScale argument to putText()?

Comment: Yeah I just need an X, 1, and 0 to be "filled" into boxes on the outputted image. fontScale seems to not want to work really. The text gets so small that it just looks like a blob of color.

Comment: I will try the FontDesigner route...thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example using both `putText()` and also loading a character from a file created in Photoshop or GIMP.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int
main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
   // Make a 3 channel image
   cv::Mat main(200,300,CV_8UC3);

   // Fill entire image with magenta
   main = cv::Scalar(255,0,255);

   // Load a character "M" from a file and overlay
   Mat txt = cv::imread("M.png",-CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
   txt.copyTo(main(cv::Rect(80,120,txt.cols,txt.rows)));

   // Now use puttext() to do a white S
   int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL;
   double fontScale=1.5;
   string text="S";
   putText(main,"S",Point(60,100),fontFace,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255));

   // Save to disk
   imwrite("result.png",main);
}
```

Here's the `M.png` file:

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

---

I also notice that the anti-aliased fonts (on the right side in image below) look somewhat easier to read:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int
main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
   // Make a 3 channel image
   cv::Mat main(280,800,CV_8UC3);

   // Fill entire image with magenta
   main = cv::Scalar(255,0,255);

   double fontScale=1.5;
   int thickness=1;
   int x=10,y=40;
   putText(main,"Simplex",Point(x,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,8);
   putText(main,"Simplex AA",Point(x+400,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,CV_AA);
   y+=40;
   putText(main,"Plain",Point(x,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,8);
   putText(main,"Plain AA",Point(x+400,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,CV_AA);
   y+=40;
   putText(main,"Duplex",Point(x,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,8);
   putText(main,"Duplex AA",Point(x+400,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,CV_AA);
   y+=40;
   putText(main,"Complex",Point(x,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,8);
   putText(main,"Complex AA",Point(x+400,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,CV_AA);
   y+=40;
   putText(main,"Triplex",Point(x,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,8);
   putText(main,"Triplex AA",Point(x+400,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,CV_AA);
   y+=40;
   putText(main,"Script",Point(x,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,8);
   putText(main,"Script AA",Point(x+400,y),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,fontScale,Scalar(255,255,255),thickness,CV_AA);

   // Save to disk
   imwrite("result.png",main);
}
```